# Creating List<Set> from a List<Object> with similar property

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
class A {
  private String x;
  private String y;
  //getters and setters
}
```

Suppose I have a list of Objects of type A. Now consider.

```
A a = new A("x","something1");
A b = new A("x","something2");
A c = new A("y","something3");
A d = new A("y","something4");

List<A> aList = new ArrayList<>();

`alist` contains a, b,c ,d
```

Can I filter the list and create a list of sublist according to the following criteria: if the value of the property x is equal group them to a sublist?

So Output should be something like.

```
List<A> someList = new ArrayList<>(); //someList contains a,b

List<A> someOtherList = new ArrayList<>(); //someOtherList contains c,d.
```

Final Output list contains someList and someOtherList.

Comment: Are you looking for `Collectors.groupingBy` ? Group the elements of the list by their `x` property, then fetch the corresponding lists.

Answer (score 4):

You may use Java 8 Stream API and [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) collector:

```
Map<String, List<A>> result = aList.stream().collect(
                 Collectors.groupingBy(A::getX));
```

This way you will get a `Map` where keys are the possible values of the field `x` and the values are lists of the corresponding `A` elements.

After that you may extract individual lists:

```
List<A> someList = result.get("x"); // contains a, b
List<A> someOtherList = result.get("y"); // contains c, d
```

If you want to group by two or more properties, you may use `Arrays.asList` as a classifier:

```
Map<List<Object>, List<A>> result = aList.stream().collect(
                 Collectors.groupingBy(a -> Arrays.asList(a.getX(), a.getY())));
```

Here you'll have a compound key represented as `List`.

Comment: suppose instead of method reference(as only for 1 property value equality) i want to check by two property values then how it can be achieved

Answer (score 4):

> If the value of the property x is equal group them to a sublist.

You said it yourself, you need to group the list by the value of the attribute `x`. With the Stream API, this is done by using the collector [`Collectors.groupingBy(classifier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-). This collector returns a map where the entries are the result of applying the given classifier to the Stream element and the values are collected into a list.

```
Map<String, List<A>> map = aList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getX));
```

This map will contain 2 entries in your case. The first will be of key `x` pointing to the elements `a` and `b`; the second will be of key `y` pointing to the elements `c` and `d`.

Answer (score 0):

@Tagir mentioned a way to do if I want to check for the equality of two property values. Just posting a different to achieve it.

```
Map<String, Collection<List<A>>> result = aList.parallelStream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getX,
             Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getY), Map::values)));
```

`parallelStream()` just in case the list is huge.